which query is executed when 'var_dump(pg_fetch_all(pg_query_params($db,'select $1=$2',[FALSE,0])))' is executed ;
While having reiterated some questions until now, I still fail to understand what exactly does 'pg_query_params' when called from PHP !!!
Having previously connected $db to a postgres database the command
var_dump(pg_fetch_all(pg_query_params($db,'select $1=$2',[FALSE,0])));

returns false as shown bellow:
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["?column?"]=>
    string(1) "f"
  }
}

while the direct execution in pgadmin of
select false=0;

returns
ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean = integer
LINE 1: select false=0 ;

so the question is where it is documented that the above results in false instead of in true ?
Similar questions for mysql_query_params and the corresponding dbo call.

You really should focus your question to one php library and one database, otherwise your question could have multiple completely different answers (one for each database - php library combination) and you can only mark one of them as accepted.

What a result of a specific query is will not be documented anywhere. How parameters are passed onto the database engine should be documented on the php side.

Php libraries are not really great at documenting the ins and outs of the bound parameters, so may need to check whatever underlying database API the php libraries call for details.

The way PostgreSQL handles that is documented in the type conversion rules.
For the undecorated query
SELECT FALSE = 0;

the first type resolves to boolean and the second to integer:
SELECT pg_typeof(FALSE);

 pg_typeof 
═══════════
 boolean

SELECT pg_typeof(0);

 pg_typeof 
═══════════
 integer

The type resolution rules find no matching = operator, hence the error message.
In the PHP code, the driver seemingly defines the parameters to have a certain data type, most likely text.  So the query that gets run is the equivalent of one of the following PostgreSQL queries:
SELECT CAST (FALSE AS text) = CAST (0 AS text);
SELECT CAST ('FALSE' AS text) = CAST ('0' AS text);

Both of these queries return FALSE.
