Postgres, what is the result of "select cast(2.000 as varchar);" ( don't execute it). Where in the docs is it explained?
Starting from question : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78580133/which-query-is-executed-when-var-dumppg-fetch-allpg-query-paramsdb-select][1] and the last answer to it naturally arises the question what is the result of "select cast(2.000 as varchar);" ( don't execute it before answering on your own). Where in the docs is it explained ?
To me the result is unexpected !!!
Answer without executing the statement, so we can check what is the "feeling" of people!

What is surprising?: select pg_typeof(cast(2.000 as varchar)); character varying same as select pg_typeof(2.000::varchar); character varying.

From the manual:

The CAST syntax conforms to SQL; the syntax with :: is historical
PostgreSQL usage.


This means we shouldn't use the :: syntax in order to be more conformant anyway !!!

@GeorgeKourtis I fully agree with you, :: should not be used in production code, only CAST(). That's standard SQL and also better understandable for non-PostgreSQL users.

To be honest, and being fully immersed in postgres ( having started from mysql though ) I didn't realize the idomatism of the :: . New rule : use CAST not ::

The ::text syntax from your original question is a postgres-style of casting, and it is mentioned in their docs as far back as 2007:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/sql-syntax.html
Without executing the query you posted, I'd expect the double 2.000 to be converted to a string... which has serious implications because "2.000" > "10" === true.
EDIT: the above link points to an old version of postgres, but has always been a valid casting syntax (postgres only). The above link is what came up when I did a quick google search for "postgres casting". Here is the link to the latest docs, the same syntax is still documented:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html

You are right !!!

I know I'm right ;). I've worked with postgres for a long time, so your example query is no more difficult than 2 + 2 is for me. Cheers.

You're joking, you are really using PostgreSQL version 7.3 ? That's EOL since 2007.

When I see 2.000 I interpret it as a double  in my mind or a float, afterwards I should convert it to something else. Instead postgres and other db's I suppose, interpret it as '2.000' so conversion to varchar or text is just an idempotent operation, but that is different from other languages (e.g. C or C++) where 2.000 is a double or float. So the lesson here is: "When you cast a litteral it is a text before being casted".

@FrankHeikens I just did a quick google search for "postgres casting" and picked the first link on the official postgres website, and I guess you're right the syntax was valid and documented as far back as 2007. It doesn't matter when the syntax was created, but that it exists and is specific to postgres.

The problem is not about syntax change it to cast( xxx as yyy)

The problem is that people keep using outdated manuals for different versions and things don't work as expected.

"When you cast a litteral it is a text before being casted" But this is not true because e.g. "select cast({3,4} as int[]);" does not give the correct result !!! and we have to write instead select cast('{3,4}' as int[]);

Because the fact something existed in 2007 does not mean it exists today. Now this particular syntax still holds, so you got away with it this time. Your answers would be more relevant if pointing at documentation from at least the same decade.

The answer has been updated with a link to the latest docs, jeez. This particular syntax has been baked into postgres since the beginning...

Also CAST(x as y) is SQL standard. :: is the Postgres shortcut.

My answer mentions first and foremost that this is a postgres-specific syntax.

@RyanWheale Then as you "worked with postgres for a long time" may be you know the answer to the starting question that is what query is executed when php issues "var_dump(pg_fetch_all(pg_query_params($db,'select $1=$2',[FALSE,0])));"

@GeorgeKourtis Both $1 and $2 are undefined data types. "false" would most likely be interpreted as a boolean, but what about the zero? That will be an integer and that won't work in the comparison. You must cast that one to a boolean. For SQL statements like this you'd better be clear and CAST your placeholders. You could cast the boolean to an integer as well

@FrankHeikens the fact is that the call returns with a result, it means that whatever is sent it is interpreted executed and a result given back. What kind of sql statement is executed ?
